# How to get table name within a 'select' statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to make an `UNION` stament like this more or less:

```
select [table_name], name, address
from Employees
where [my_condition]

UNION

select [table_name], name, address
from Employees_history
where [my_condition]
```

The data retrieved will be in either Employees or Employees_history but not in both tables.

I need to know which table the data comes from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Employees' AS [table_name],
       name,
       address
FROM   Employees
WHERE  [my_condition]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Employees_history' AS [table_name],
       name,
       address
FROM   Employees_history
WHERE  [my_condition]
```

I use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` as there will be no duplicates across the two branches. So it can avoid some unnecessary work removing duplicates across the whole result set.

If there might be duplicates within branch(es) add `DISTINCT` to the individual `SELECT`(s)

Answer (score 1):

You can append a new field as shown below:

```
select [table_name], name, address, 'Employees'
from Employees
where [my_condition]

UNION

select [table_name], name, address, 'History'
from Employees_history
where [my_condition]
```

You can also use an `alias` as Martin has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
select 'Employees' as table_name, name, address
from Employees
where [my_condition]

UNION

select 'Employees_history' as table_name, name, address
from Employees_history
where [my_condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved [Using Table Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
SELECT 'Employees' AS [table_name],
       name,
       address
FROM   Employees
WHERE  [my_condition]

UNION

SELECT 'History' AS [table_name],
       name,
       address
FROM   Employees_history
WHERE  [my_condition]
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually use any table aliases.